# Laptop CPU overheats regulary, how to stop it?

Tags: laptop, processor, motherboard, heat-sink, fan-controller

Specs:

- Intel core i5-7200U @2.5GHz, 2 Cores
- Turbo ON:     **-Current clock speed:3.1 GHz**    -min clock speed:
  0.4GHz    -max clock speed: 2.7GHz
- Turbo ON temperature: -low 70 C **-current 95 C** -high 95 C
- Turbo OFF:     -**Current clock speed:2.4 GHz**    -min clock speed:
  0.4GHz    -max clock speed: 2.7GHz
- Turbo OFF temperature: -low 49 C  **-current 49 C** -high 68 C

Background:

When I have the CPU turbo on the CPU goes to max temp 95 C very quickly and the fan speeds up making a laud noise, even when a web browser is open and no power cable plugged in. The current clock speed is :3.1 GHz all the time in the bios report. In task manager the CPU goes to 3.1 GHz even for small tasks. When I have turbo mode off there is little fan noise but more when power cable is plugged in.

Questions:

- Should the copper heatsink be touching the two silver metal parts by
  the CPU? There is a gap and when I put the case back on it does not
  close the gap much.
- Should I buy heatsink pads to put pressure onto the copper heatsink
  so it touches the silver metal parts when I put the case back on? Stick pads to the case so it  touches the copper heatsink.
- How can I stop the CPU from overheating?

Two silver metal parts by CPU
[image]
Copper Heatsink:
[image]
Case on:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you, but I believe the CPU is just off the Right of your second photo. Yes, there must be an uninterrupted "heat path" from the CPU (far right) through the Heat Pipe (actually an internally porous liquid/vapour heat exchange system) into the Cooling fins. If you can check the temperature while its running: if the pipe is hot and the fins cool, there is a break between them. Similarly if the pipe is cool and the cpu reads hot, then the cooler needs to be reseated onto the cpu (with thermal paste). (In laptops,may not be easy to do. Definitely google/youtube your model).

Comment: Try taking all the dust out of your laptop and put it on a hard table if it's on a soft material.

Comment: Having owned a very similar cpu with what looks like a similar laptop, this is normal behaviour. The cooling fins are basically the absolute minimum that cpu needs.
Turbo mode allows it to boost above its normal speeds as long as there is thermal headroom. For a laptop cpu those temperatures are normally 95C, so with the small amount of cooling, sadly this is expected behaviour. If the laptop was quieter on purchase. It might be worth removing the cooler, removing the thermal paste and adding new paste. However with laptop coolers being on die only do this when you have some experience.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes the CPU is on the right. I will replace cooling paste and test the copper pipes. I can then test turbo. I think there is not enough cooling for the type of CPU. It is constantly hot when a game is running but the CPU keeps going. The CPU has always done this but it has got worse. I like CPUs that have smaller margin between the base speed and turbo speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the CPU thermal paste and drilled holes around  the bottom of the laptop casing to allow air to get in. I also got a laptop cooler stand. I upgraded the RAM too

I ran two CPU tests in the BIOS. I get around:

- High 89C
- Low 56C
- Current 56C

I have not used the laptop cooling stand much. There was not much difference with the cooling fan stand on or off but it was on for a short period.